# WMI Win32_Share.Create method on localhost via WMI on Server OSes gives Error Code 24

Tags: c#, wmi

I am detecting whether or not I'm attempting a connection against localhost, and creating (or not) the WMI connection options as follows:

```
if (NetworkUtils.IsLocalIpAddress(machineName))
{
    _scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", machineName));
}
else
{
    _connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions
    {
        Username = username,
        Password = password,
        Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
    };

    _scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", machineName), _connectionOptions);
}
```

When I call `_scope.Connect()` in either case, it works. That is, no exception and `IsConnected` is true.

However, when I attempt to invoke a method in the local case, such as `Win32_Share.Create` I get errors. The following code *always* works for remote connections for me:

```
var winSharePath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Share");
var winShareClass = new ManagementClass(_scope, winSharePath, null);
var shareParams = winShareClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
shareParams["Path"] = pathName.TrimEnd('\\');
shareParams["Name"] = shareName;
shareParams["Type"] = 0;
shareParams["Description"] = "CMC Bootstrap Share";
var outParams = winShareClass.InvokeMethod("Create", shareParams, null);

if ((uint) (outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
{
    throw new Exception("Unable to share directory. Error code: " +
                        outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value);
}
```

I create the `pathName` directory just prior to invoking this method, so I guarantee `pathName` exists in all cases.

When executing locally *ONLY on Windows Server 2008 & 2012*, the above code throws the exception with error code 24. Executing against localhost on Windows 8 works just fine.

What is the correct way to specify "blank credentials" when invoking WMI methods against localhost, as I believe this is the underlying issue?

Comment: I think you don't need the machinename in the scope when it's localhost. Try this one `ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\cimv2");`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code below on my local PC and this works (shares my temp folder). Could you try the same please? Also, which is the patch & share name you're using?

```
        string pathName = @"c:\temp\";
        string shareName = "tempFolder";
        var scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", "localhost"));

        // your code below
        var winSharePath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Share");
        var winShareClass = new ManagementClass(scope, winSharePath, null);
        var shareParams = winShareClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        shareParams["Path"] = pathName.TrimEnd('\\');
        shareParams["Name"] = shareName;
        shareParams["Type"] = 0;
        shareParams["Description"] = "CMC Bootstrap Share";
        var outParams = winShareClass.InvokeMethod("Create", shareParams, null);

        if ((uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to share directory. Error code: " +
                                outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value);
        }
```

Comment: I neglected to mention the code works on desktop OSes and fails on server OSes.

Comment: Lol, nice addon :)    In what type of program is the code executed? winforms/wpf started by a user with enough priv.? or web-app in iis? And have you tried impersonating with an admin account on the server?

Comment: WPF app. Runs elevated. The code works fine against any remote machine. The problem is specific to local host on server OSes. Weird right?

Comment: I don't think you can impersonate on localhost, at least not on server OSes.

Comment: I've run @codemonkey's code on Windows Server 2012 (non-R2) in an .NET 4.0 WPF app executed with "Run as administrator" (UAC is on default settings) and it **does work** (creates a share on c:\temp and ReturnValue is 0). You need to provide more detail on how to reproduce

Answer (score 2):

> the above code throws the exception with error code 24

That doesn't have anything to do with the error you mention in the title of your question.  Error codes for Win32_Share.Create method are documented in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Return value 24 means "Unknown Device or Directory".

In other words, your `pathName` variable is wrong.

Comment: The path is fine, because it does work in most cases. It works against remote machines, and local host on windows 8. It fails on localhost on server 2008/2012.

Comment: That's not what error 24 says. What specific directories are available on a machine to get turned into shares is of course heavily dependent on the specific machine.  Any undebuggable problem starts with a wrong assumption about the bug.  Btw, you need to edit your question and reconcile the title of the question with the body.

Comment: I create and then share out the exact same path on every machine. The *only* variable at play here is localhost on a server OS.

Comment: You don't realize that "exact same path" is what causes this problem.  Giving them the same share name is fine, but your local machine doesn't have that source path.  I have no idea how to make that clearer, good luck with it.

Comment: You're incredibly condescending and not helpful. I just said "I create and then share out the exact same path on every machine." I have no idea how to make that clearer.